# Spring MVC preauthorize Controller action not getting POST request

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring-mvc, http-status-code-405

A noob at Spring MVC and Ajax stuff. I'm trying to send some data from the view to the controller using jQuery Ajax post but its either giving me 405 `handleHttpRequestMethodNotSupported` or 403 :-( Could someone please point me in the right direction?

This is my controller action that is `preAuthorize`.

```
@PreAuthorize( "hasAuthority('Admin')" )
@RequestMapping( value = "/configSave", method = RequestMethod.POST )
public String saveConfiguration( @RequestParam String test )
{
    return "configSave";
}
```

Following is the code from the page from where the post request is being sent.

```
...
<input type="button" value="Save" id="save" onclick="saveConfig()"/>
...
function saveConfig()
    {
        var testPost = { test: "testing"};

        $.ajax(
                {
                    url: "hello/configSave",
                    data: "{'test':'testing'}",
                    contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                    type: "post",
                    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                        xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
                        xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
                    },
                    success: function () {
                        alert("foo");
                    },
                    error: function() {
                        alert("bar");
                    }
                }
        );
    }
```

All it does is it throws me either a 403 (for now, else 405) error with `bar` alert.

**EDIT:**
Surprisingly, when I don't do ajax post (which I need to do) it calls the `configSave` action in the controller. Just really puzzled with this behaviour!

Comment: headers="Accept=application/json" try adding this in your requestMapping

Comment: @DejanBiljecki - Nope, not working with that either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Managed to find a couple of sections in Spring docs [this](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/reference/htmlsingle/#csrf-include-csrf-token-ajax) and [this](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/reference/htmlsingle/#the-csrfmetatags-tag) which says that I need to use CSRF token to send a post request across, when using Spring Security. After a lot of test and trail I found the following code working for me. I hope it helps others too. Any better suggestions are welcomed.

```
...<%@ taglib prefix="sec" uri="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags" %>...

...<sec:csrfMetaTags />...//Within <head>

...var csrfToken = $("meta[name='_csrf']").attr("content");...//somewhere in page load

function saveConfig()
    {
        var test = { name: "testing" };

        $.ajax(
                {
                    url: "hello/configSave",
                    data: JSON.stringify( test ),
                    dataType: "text",
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    type: "post",
                    headers: {
                        'Accept': 'application/json',
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': csrfToken //adding this made it WORK!
                    },
                    success: function (msg) {
                        alert("Yippie! Saved");
                    },
                    error: function() {
                        alert("Save failed, please try again!");
                    }
                }
        );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `headers = "Accept=application/json"`

replace `contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",` by `contentType : "application/json",`

There are lots of moving parts here. Why don't you break it down and verify in smaller parts. Create similar code outside `Spring authentication`. Once you have `Ajax` working, then you can add `Spring authentication` back. `403` has nothing to do with `405`. Since, this is just header mis-match and other is security issue.

Comment: Nope. no luck with that either. `403 (Forbidden)`  this time :-(

Comment: @KunalPatel Remove -- `@PreAuthorize( "hasAuthority('Admin')" )` and try. Forbidden is a better error :)

Comment: are you using spring security?

Comment: @java_dude, if I remove that I still get the same 403. 
Dejan, yes I am using Spring Security.

Comment: I tested it with a sample project and it works fine over there without spring security. Its still throwing me 403!!

Comment: @KunalPatel then its a security issue, which is a different issue.